# Smallest $\mathbb R^n$ into which $SO(3)$ can be topologically embedded?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, differential-topology, topological-groups

I think there are theorems in differential geometry guaranteeing that $SO(3)$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$. But do we know what particular $n$ this is for $SO(3)$, and do we know of a particular embedding?

This would be nice to know if $n$ happens to be small enough for us to "think about" the global topology of $SO(3)$ in a somewhat geometrical way.

Comment: The smallest is n=5. The rest of your questions are too unclear.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Maybe I just don't know enough differential geometry, but I would have thought that "specifying a particular embedding" is a precise notion. What's unclear about it?

Comment: Why all the logic tags? This seems to be a question about differential geometry...

Comment: @AlexKruckman Whoops, they were left over from a question I started to write and then deleted. I updated these ones, thanks.

Comment: For a concrete embedding, think of a rotation around an axis $v$ and angle $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ as the point $v\theta$. This creates a ball of radius $\pi$. Then glue together the opposite points on the surface.

Comment: @Trebor That's a nice way to think about it. Though I still wonder if there's a way that doesn't require any quotienting.

Comment: While it isn't a true topological embedding, one can [identify $SO(3)$ with the space of unit quaternions in $\mathbb{H}\cong\mathbb{R}^4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), quotionted by the relation $q\sim -q$. This is somewhat easier to think about "geometrically" than most other constructions of $SO(3)$ (particularly with regard to the standard bi-invariant metric).

Comment: A lazy (but still very ueseful) embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{3 \cdot 3}$ comes from looking at elements of $SO(3)$ as $3 \times 3$ matrices. But the question is unclear to me, I don't know what this embedding is needed for.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the comment of @MoisheKohan, the smallest such $n$ is $5$, but the way things work is not that one finds the global topology of $SO(3)$ via some "nice embedding" into $\mathbb R^5$. On the contrary, one first observes that, as a manifold, $SO(3)$ is diffeomorphic to the real projective space $\mathbb RP^3$. This projective space is obtained by identifying antipodal points in the three-sphere $S^3$ (similarly as the projective plane is obtained from the two-sphere). Alternatively, you can describe it as the space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb R^4$. For projective spaces it is known that they are particularly difficult to embed into $\mathbb R^n$, in particular, $\mathbb RP^3$ embeds into $\mathbb R^5$ but not into $\mathbb R^4$.

The identifiacation of $SO(3)$ winth $\mathbb RP^3$ can be obtained in a rather direct way by realizing $SO(3)$ as a quotient group of either the unit quaternions as mentioned in the comment of @Kajelad or of $SU(2)$, in both cases by identifying each element with its negative. The unit quaternions are the unit sphere in $\mathbb H\cong\mathbb R^4$ on the nose and hence an $S^3$. For $SU(2)$ one easily verifies that mapping $A\in SU(2)$ to its first column vector identifies $SU(2)$ with unit vectors in $\mathbb C^2\cong\mathbb R^4$, so again this is a $3$-sphere.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm still curious about what the embedding from $\mathbb{RP}^3\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^5$ looks like, even if it isn't "nice." Is no such explicit embedding known, or is it just difficult to write down?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the fact that $\mathbb{R}P^3$ can't be (smoothly) embedded into $\mathbb{R}^4$?  The usual obstructions (involving characteristic classes) vanish since $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is parallelizable.

Comment: Here's a reference that shows that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ never embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96583/is-it-true-that-all-real-projective-space-rpn-can-not-be-smoothly-embedded-in

Answer (score 4):

The standard reference I know is

*Massey, W. S.*, [**On the imbeddability of the real projective spaces in Euclidean space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1959.9.783), Pac. J. Math. 9, 783-789 (1959). [ZBL0094.36003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0094.36003).

Namely, $RP^n$ can never embed topologically in $R^{n+1}$ for any $n\ge 2$. Massey credits Rene Thom with this result.

Alternatively (in the smooth setting), one can quote Theorem A in

*Levine, J.*, [**Imbedding and immersion of real projective spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2034999), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 14, 801-803 (1963). [ZBL0117.17007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0117.17007).

The group $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic (actually, diffeomorphic) to the projective space $RP^3$, hence, it cannot embed topologically in $R^4$. At the same time, every 3-dimensional manifold embeds smoothly in $R^5$. This theorem is due to Hirsch in the orientable case (and $RP^3$ is orientable):

*Hirsch, Morris W.*, [**On imbedding differentiable manifolds in Euclidean space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970318), Ann. Math. (2) 73, 566-571 (1961). [ZBL0123.16701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0123.16701).

and, independently, Rokhlin and Wall for non-orientable manifolds.

An explicit embedding $RP^3\to R^5$ (and much more) was constructed in

*James, I. M.*, Some embeddings of projective spaces, Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 55, 294-298 (1959). [ZBL0090.13201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0090.13201).

However, I find it extremely unlikely that you would gain better understanding of the topology of $RP^3$ using such an embedding. For instance, I am unaware of anybody who understands better the real projective plane using its embedding in $R^4$ (or immersion in $R^3$)  comparing to the standard descriptions of real-projective spaces.